# how to do cross-validation with quanteda?

Tags: r, r-caret, naivebayes, quanteda

Consider the following example

```
dtrain <- data_frame(text = c("Chinese Beijing Chinese",
                              "Chinese Chinese Shanghai",
                              "Chinese Macao",
                              "Tokyo Japan Chinese"),
                     doc_id = 1:4,
                     class = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "N"))

dtrain <- dtrain %>% mutate(class = as.factor(class))

> dtrain
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  text                     doc_id class
  <chr>                     <int> <fct>
1 Chinese Beijing Chinese       1 Y    
2 Chinese Chinese Shanghai      2 Y    
3 Chinese Macao                 3 Y    
4 Tokyo Japan Chinese           4 N
```

The following code, which trains a naive bayes classifier on this textual data, works well:

```
trainingset <- dfm(corpus(dtrain, docid_field = 'doc_id', text_field = 'text'))

nb_test <- textmodel_nb(trainingset, docvars(trainingset, "class"), prior = "docfreq")
myprediction <- predict(nb_test, trainingset)$nb.predicted

confusionMatrix(table(trainingclass, myprediction), mode = 'prec_recall')


Confusion Matrix and Statistics

             myprediction
trainingclass N Y
            N 1 0
            Y 0 3

               Accuracy : 1          
                 95% CI : (0.3976, 1)
    No Information Rate : 0.75       
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.3164     

                  Kappa : 1          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA         

              Precision : 1.00       
                 Recall : 1.00       
                     F1 : 1.00
```

My problem is that this is just `in-sample`.

In other words I do not know how I can use tools like `caret` to do some basic cross-validation (careful, my classes are highly imbalanced in the data) and optimize over, say, `F1`. It seems `quanteda` is not compatible with `caret`. How to perform cross-validation efficiently then?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: If the question is how do you predict out of sample using `textmodel_nb()`, the answer is in changing the `newdata` argument. See `?predict.textmodel_nb`.

Comment: Do you mean to train a naive bayes model based on `quanteda` and `caret`? Or use `quanteda` to preprocess everything and use caret to handle the cross validation and training? I'm asking this because the naive bayes in `caret` are either from the `naivebayes` or from the `klaR` package. You could always built your own cross validation or use `h2o` if you need more speed. Having a imbalanced dataset is of course part of the game :-)

Comment: @phiver its a good point. I guess the question is how to perform cross validation and sample split while using quanteda. I did noy realize that caret does not support quanteda actually!!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ, in that case either look at [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61090/how-to-split-a-data-set-to-do-10-fold-cross-validation#105839) to do your own splits or build `quanteda` into `caret` as described [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html) on how to add models to `caret`. If I have some time this week I might actually have a better look into this.

Comment: @phiver, interesting, thanks! yes it would be nice if `quanteda` was supported natively in `caret`.. So I guess I am closing this for now. Thanks again to both of you

Comment: Feel free to open a feature request issue at https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues.